# How add searchResultsTableView with constraints equal to the uitableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I create simple view controller with table view and search display controller. When I added search display controller it create `NSAutoResizingMaskConstraints` for `searchResultsTableView` and take whole place in view controller. But I use autoLayout for this viewController and my `tableView` has a limited space.

Does anybody know how add constraints to a `searchResultsTableView`?

**What I already tried:**

I set `searchResultsTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO`, but my UITableViewCell has autolayout too, and when I create my cell i see `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` error. This is weird because when i create this cell for `tableView` i dont see error. Cell created in StoryBoard like prototype for `tableView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this with constraints, but you can achieve the result you want by using a container view in the main controller set to whatever size you want your table views to be. The table view and the search results table view will both be the full size of this embedded controller. So, the storyboard would look like this:

[image]

Comment: If I understand you, I have to create controller with container and in container will be another controller? I don't know how to do this in storyboard :(

I tried insert table view in another view but this isn't work.

Comment: @IceFloe, you just drag a container view (not a regular UIView) into ViewController, and size it how you want. You automatically get a UIViewController attached to it by an embed segue. If you want a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController, delete the attached controller, drag out a table view controller, control drag from the container to to the table view controller, and choose embed.

Comment: Thank you [rdelmar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1285133/rdelmar)! This helped me a lot in avoiding additional constraints! This approach is much better than to modify the search display controllers table view, what many people try to do.